# ADF Schedule/trigger 50 days after month end

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to schedule an ADF pipeline 50 days after month end. These are the sample dates:-

- 31/Jan/21 - 22/Mar/21
- 28/Feb/21 - 19/Apr/21
- 31/Mar/21 - 20/May/21

How can I achieve it?

Comment: The way I normally see this done is to run the pipeline every day and have some logic in the pipeline which determines what do to, eg Lookup activity, is day 50 days after month-end, if so run another activity, otherwise exit.  Can work up an example if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parent-child pipeline  -

schedule it to run everyday

in it - collect current date in a variable and subtract 50 days

Use if activity and check if the value obtained is last day of any month then trigger
nested pipeline to run that particular code

Comment: We could also use the same setup and get an external csv with a calender and input data. In this case we have the option to add additional out of schedule days if needed. This was how I implemented it.